# Adding a navigation bar to a web view in a tab bar app

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

I've built the tab bar application in IB, with three tabs. The third tab happily displays a UIWebview where you can browse. The only thing missing is a back button, as not all web pages supply such a link.

I need a navigation bar hooked up properly to the correct classes. I'm still a bit unsure about exactly how the hierarchy should look in interface builder and how to hook it up properly.

Currently, the third tab is hooked up to a referencing outlet called 'webnews' in the class 'thirdviewcontroller', and the UIWebView (under a normal IUView in the hierarchy, which in turn is under the third tab bar controller) is connected to the webnews outlet.

How do I make the navbar control the webview, and do I add code to the thirdviewcontroller.m that lets the navbar on the view control the webview 'back' function? What do I hook up as the delegate for it? Currently I have an app delegate, but that's hooked up to the tab bar.

I'm not really after specific code as much as a general 'how it works' clue :) (Unless I can just add the navbar dynamically to the functioning app... but I don't think addSubView on viewWillAppear {} in thirdviewcontroller.m will create the proper functionality?)

If I were to guess at the simplest solution, I'd guess create a navbarcontroller.h/.m, slap a navbar on the view in IB, connect the third tab to navbarcontroller, connect the navbar to the webview (?) and move the webnews outlet to navbarcontroller.h, and connect the webview to it. But I don't quite have the nerve to try, better to ask advice first.

Comment: After some thought, I don't really need a navigation controller, do I? Since the Webview doesn't really have view switching and can handle itself on its own. I've added a navbar to the view and will try to make a button on it go to a specific URL.

Comment: Just adding a navigation bar works fine, pushing and popping items works as well. There doesn't seem to be any way of setting actions for buttons though, even if I make them UIBarButtons, nor does it seem possible to find anything to override to detect item clicks in the delegate.

A navigation bar is hard-coded for 'history' type operations only? No way to make a 'jump all the way to "start"' button?

Since the boss wants a navbar, I'm looking at styling a normal toolbar to look like one. Will probably not get the neat animation, but what the hey. Thankful for any advice you can give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering this, see similar [Detect and handle, or override, clicks on a navigation bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942045/detect-and-handle-or-override-clicks-on-a-navigation-bar)